# Using vanitygen To generate addresses for different cryptocurrencies

Tags: vanitygen

I know how to use vanitygen but how do you determine the number that will correspond to the -X parameter for a different cryptocurrency? For example it is -X 30 for Dogecoin.

Comment: Here's the biggest list yet: https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus/blob/master/vanitygen.c#L547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some [here](http://cryptocurrencies.comule.com/tag/vanitygen/).

- LTC: 48
- FTC: 14
- NVC: 8
- ANC: 23
- PTC: 47
- CNC: 28
- DGC:30
- NMC: 52
- PPC:55
- YAC: 77
- BQC: 85
- IXC: 138
- DOGE: 30

Proper syntax for VanityGen is: (from [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/701/edit) question)

```
Usage: vanitygen [-vqrikNT] [-t <threads>] [-f <filename>|-] [<pattern>...]
Generates a bitcoin receiving address matching <pattern>, and outputs the
address and associated private key.  The private key may be stored in a safe
location or imported into a bitcoin client to spend any balance received on
the address.
By default, <pattern> is interpreted as an exact prefix.

Options:
-v            Verbose output
-q            Quiet output
-r            Use regular expression match instead of prefix
              (Feasibility of expression is not checked)
-i            Case-insensitive prefix search
-k            Keep pattern and continue search after finding a match
-N            Generate namecoin address
-T            Generate bitcoin testnet address
-X <version>  Generate address with the given version
-t <threads>  Set number of worker threads (Default: number of CPUs)
-f <file>     File containing list of patterns, one per line
              (Use "-" as the file name for stdin)
-o <file>     Write pattern matches to <file>
-s <file>     Seed random number generator from <file>
```

Comment: That is pretty helpful. Do you know more. And what is the -k for?

Comment: Added the whole helpfile for vanitygen, from a different question. That'll help a lot :)

Comment: One last thing. How do you access previous results or save a result? And is there any complete list for these -X addresses except the link you provided?

Comment: In bash you can do something like `codeThatGeneratesSomething > output.txt` iirc. Then it will be in output.txt instead of the shell. Because the private keys are also in there IN PLAIN TEXT, be sure to use it WISELY.

Comment: Sorry I am a complete noob to this. I don't know what is bash and all. Isn't there an inbuilt command in vanity gen to save the output? I also see some OCLBIN files what are they?

Comment: Bash is the terminal you use it in :). So you append `> output.txt` behind the command you are using it. But the `-o <file>` does exactly what you want, and it is easier. Didn't read it (and you didn't either)

Comment: Ohh sorry I forgot to mention that I use windows. And what is the .oclbin file and how to open it?

Comment: If you want to use the option -k for something, you can also use the -o option.

Comment: And what is the point of using -k? You have already got your desired result. How can there be more patterns. Please can you give me an example?

Comment: Maybe if the Pizzahut wants to make btc-deposit addresses for their 100 different pizza-delivery boys, for clients to tip. It would be nice if all addresses contain 'PizzaHutDeliveryboyTipContest'. Or whatever. You and your wife (or husband) want to have addresses that both contain 'WeLoveEachotherVeryMuch'? Or you just want to select the best of 10 generated addresses? For example, if there is a swear in one, you want to drop that one (Imagine 'f*CkPizzaHut' as address).

Comment: Ohh ok thanks. And Just one last thing. Are there more of those -X addresses and how do you find them?

Comment: I cannot find more of the -X options. I just googled for it and came accross the linked site.

Comment: Do you also know how to use multiple GPU's. I cannot get it working.

Comment: No, I don't know that. Just be patient, let it run for a while. Or ask a new question